# Не работает post в django api rest framwork

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Я кажись плохо искал в инете. Пришлось сюда обращаюсь
Вот модельки

```py
class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MealCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    departamentid = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Вот serializer

```py
class MealCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MealCategory
        fields = '__all__'
```

Это view

```py
class MealCategoryViewList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        mealcategories = MealCategory.objects.all()
        serializer = MealCategorySerializer(mealcategories, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = MealCategorySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

При запросе  post

```
{
    "name": "Vtoroe",
    "departmentid": 2
}
```

Не сахраняет в БД
Посмотрел error какие получаеться. Для этого дабавил строчку  в `view
print(serializer.error_messages)`
Вышло это -

```
{'required': 'This field is required.', 'null': 'This field may not be null.', 'invalid': 'Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got {datatype}.'}
```

А теперь вопрос как надо поменять view или serializer чтобы оно работало?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас опечатка в теле запроса, исправьте на

```
{
    "name": "Vtoroe",
    "departamentid": 2
}
```

Ошибки можно вернуть в Response, как и созданный объект:

```
def post(self, request):
    serializer = MealCategorySerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: У меня опечатка не в теле запроса, а в модельке. Правильно пишется все таки department. Исправил все заработало спасибо.